# for loop's List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I make each symbol from lowercase to be paired with each symbol from digits?

```
lowercase = 'abcdef'
digits = '012'
```

The following returns generator:

```
(((i + (lambda x: y)(digits)) for y in digits) for i in lowercase)
```

What I have found is either **list()** or **[]** around generator should return the right content but neither of ones below ever worked:

```
print(list((((i + (lambda x: y)(digits)) for y in digits) for i in lowercase)))
print(list(((i + (lambda x: y)(digits)) for y in digits) for i in lowercase))
print(list((i + (lambda x: y)(digits)) for y in digits) for i in lowercase)
print(list(i + (lambda x: y)(digits) for y in digits) for i in lowercase)
print([(i + (lambda x: y)(digits) for y in digits)] for i in lowercase)
[<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329D80>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329DB0>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329DE0>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E10>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E40>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E70>]
[<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329D80>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329DB0>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329DE0>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E10>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E40>, <generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x03329E70>]
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01605E70>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01605E70>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01605E70>
```

Comment: Do you know what a generator is and why it is that you are getting a generator based on the solution you wrote?

Comment: I guess if I knew I wouldn't post the question here

Comment: What's the point of `(lambda x: y)(digits)`...?

Comment: yeah, that lambda looks weird

Comment: @feedthemachine My question was trying to determine the nature of your question, and understand where you were coming from with your question to better understand how to help you on the free help site. But hey, I guess you being sarcastic was the best choice?

Comment: probably, I just need to have each symbol from the second list to be iterated with each symbol from the first list and have a list of all possible outcomes at the end. Unfortunately, I have not found any good documentation on this

Comment: to be more precise, `(lambda x: y)(digits)` creates a function that takes one argument, discards that argument, and returns whatever the name `y` points to. Then `digits` is passed to that function, discarded, and you get `y`. Therfore, `(lambda x: y)(digits)` is equivalent to `y`.

Comment: Either `list(itertools.product(lowercase, digits))` for a list of tuples or `[''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(lowercase, digits)]` for a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it what you want  if i have understood you correctly

```
lowercase = 'abcdef'
digits = '012'

[letter+digit for letter in lowercase for digit in digits]

>>>['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'd0', 'd1', 'd2', 'e0', 'e1', 'e2', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2']
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to have the same result using lambda expression

Comment: do you want to create a function (using ``lambda``) that  returns the list of combination?

Comment: ``f = lambda letters, digits: [l+d for l in letters for d in digits]`` check the result ``print(f(lowercase, digits))``

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions surrounded by round brackets create a generator, square brackets create a list:
Btw. you could rewrite the lambda expression, using string formatting:

```
>>> lowercase = 'abcdef'
>>> digits = '012'
>>> 
>>> ["%s%s" % (c, d) for c in lowercase for d in digits]
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'd0', 'd1', 'd2', 'e0', 'e1', 'e2', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2']
>>> ("%s%s" % (c, d) for c in lowercase for d in digits)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f0d558b64b0>
```

Comment: **print([lambda x, y: letter+digit for letter in lowercase for digit in digits])** doesn't seem to work as <function <listcomp>.<lambda>  is returned